# What is the criteria for a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

In euclidean space, what is the criteria for a plane? Is $\mathbb R^2$ a plane itself?

\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
let $x$ = an element of $\mathbb R$, let $y$ = a element of $\mathbb R$.

EDIT:
Is a normal vector one of the criteria for a plane? If $\mathbb R^2$ exists in $\mathbb R^2$ then does it need a normal vector?

Comment: Here is a try. Two 3-dimensional independent vectors in R3 span a set of points that form a plane. Or here is another one: Given a line in space. Pick one point on that line. Every normal with that point as its terminal point spans a plane in R3. Of course R2 is a plane on its own in the 2 dimensional world, we call it the xy-coordinate plane or Cartesian plane, named after the French mathematician Rene Descartes

Comment: @imranfat I made an edit. I am confused by the nonexistence of the normal vector for R2(If R2 is in R2).

Comment: If R2 is to be considered in R2 then there is no normal vector. But we can't say R2 in R3. W can say the xy-plane in R3. And then there is a normal vector too, the z-axis. I think (but I got to be careful now) for a normal vector to exist, one has to be one dimension higher than the the plane itself

Comment: You don't need normal vectors to define a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. A plane is defined as a set of all points with the coordinates $x$, $y$, and $z$ which satisfy $ax+by+cz+d=0$ for some constant parameters $a, b, c, d$ such that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are not all simultaneously equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

In an $n$-dimensional vector space the term “plane” refers usually to a $2$- or $n-1$- dimensional subspace; the latter are also called “hyperplanes”.